# Why zenity color selection piping to sed breaks the code?

Tags: shell, sed, scripting, hex, zenity

I am trying use sed to convert 12 digit hex code returned from zenity's --color-selection dialogue into 6 digit hex code. for example: #dfe251a951a9 to #df5151.
but as soon as i use sed in the following code it breaks the whole script, and when i select "select" or "cancel" buttons i dont get respective echo! what's the problem?

*before using sed: everything works nice but i get 12 digit hex code.*

```
#!/bin/bash
color=$(zenity --color-selection)
if [[ $? == 0 ]]
then 
    echo "You selected $color."
else [[ $? == 1 ]]
    echo "No color selected."
fi
```

*after using sed: when i hit select button i get 6 digit hex code but when i hit cancel i dont get "no color selected", it echoes "You selected ."*

```
#!/bin/bash
color=$(zenity --color-selection | sed 's/\(#\?..\)../\1/g')
if [[ $? == 0 ]]
then 
    echo "You selected $color."
else [[ $? == 1 ]]
    echo "No color selected."
fi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After

```
color=$(zenity --color-selection | sed 's/\(#\?..\)../\1/g')
```

`$?` is the exit status of `sed` (not `zenity`)<sup>1</sup>, which is 0. You could use

```
#!/bin/bash
color=$(zenity --color-selection)

# Now $? is the exit status of zenity
if [[ $? == 0 ]]
then
    # Process with sed only if necessary.
    color=$(echo "$color" | sed 's/\(#\?..\)../\1/g')
    echo "You selected $color"
else
    echo "No color selected."
fi
```

**Note**, by the way, that my version of `zenity` (3.16.2) does not return a hexadecimal code but something of the form `rgb(12,34,56)`. I have not investigated when or why this change happened, but it may not be wise to rely on a particular format.

<sup>1</sup> More precisely: It's the exit status of the subshell spawned by `$()`, which just forwards the exit status of the last command it ran: the `sed` call.

Comment: Yeah that works fine. Thanks. just new to shell scripting, but your tip do the job. 6 digit hexadecimal and that of you rgb are familiar and there are so many stuff to convert em but 12 digit is somehow weird and i think many out there are unaccostomed to this color format ;)

Comment: zenity (3.42.1) does return the rgb(...) form. First I thought it will break the imagemagick -xc: option, but magick/convert accepts this form which is in my eyes a more informative one specifying the used rgb color scheme (not for example hsv or bgr).